# Page not found with Django

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django following onemonth.com. 
I tried to link using {% static (URLs) %} to load static files but it doesn't load. Could someone help me? I put my codes in files below.

> settings.py(only changed parts)

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MAIN_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'coffeedapp.urls'    
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(MAIN_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'coffeedapp.wsgi.application'

import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIRS= (
    os.path.join(MAIN_DIR,'static'),
)
```

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
class LandingView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'base/index.html'
```

> core/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import core.views as coreviews

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$', coreviews.LandingView.as_view()),
                       )
```

> coffeedapp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns,include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       (r'', include('core.urls')),
                       )
```

> index.html (partial)

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Agency - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{% static "css/agency.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="{% static "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="page-top" class="index">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro-text">
                <div class="intro-lead-in">Welcome To Our Studio!</div>
                <div class="intro-heading">It's Nice To Meet You</div>
                <a href="#services" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Tell Me More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Services Section -->
    <section id="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Services</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                    </span>
                    <h4 class="service-heading">E-Commerce</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                    </span>
                    <h4 class="service-heading">Responsive Design</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-lock fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                    </span>
                    <h4 class="service-heading">Web Security</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Portfolio Grid Section -->
    <section id="portfolio" class="bg-light-gray">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Portfolio</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="{% static "img/portfolio/roundicons.png" %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>Round Icons</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Graphic Design</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal2" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="{% static "img/portfolio/startup-framework.png" %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>Startup Framework</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Website Design</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal3" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="{% static "img/portfolio/treehouse.png" %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>Treehouse</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Website Design</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal4" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="{% static "img/portfolio/golden.png" %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>Golden</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Website Design</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal5" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="{% static "img/portfolio/escape.png" %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>Escape</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Website Design</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal6" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="{% static "img/portfolio/dreams.png" %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>Dreams</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Website Design</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- About Section -->
    <section id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">About</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <ul class="timeline">
                        <li>
                            <div class="timeline-image">
                                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="{% static "img/about/1.jpg" %}" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-panel">
                                <div class="timeline-heading">
                                    <h4>2009-2011</h4>
                                    <h4 class="subheading">Our Humble Beginnings</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline-body">
                                    <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="timeline-inverted">
                            <div class="timeline-image">
                                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="{% static "img/about/2.jpg" %}" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-panel">
                                <div class="timeline-heading">
                                    <h4>March 2011</h4>
                                    <h4 class="subheading">An Agency is Born</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline-body">
                                    <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="timeline-image">
                                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="{% static "img/about/3.jpg" %}" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-panel">
                                <div class="timeline-heading">
                                    <h4>December 2012</h4>
                                    <h4 class="subheading">Transition to Full Service</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline-body">
                                    <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="timeline-inverted">
                            <div class="timeline-image">
                                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="{% static "img/about/4.jpg" %}" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-panel">
                                <div class="timeline-heading">
                                    <h4>July 2014</h4>
                                    <h4 class="subheading">Phase Two Expansion</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline-body">
                                    <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="timeline-inverted">
                            <div class="timeline-image">
                                <h4>Be Part
                                    <br>Of Our
                                    <br>Story!</h4>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Team Section -->
    <section id="team" class="bg-light-gray">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Our Amazing Team</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="team-member">
                        <img src="img/team/1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="">
                        <h4>Kay Garland</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Lead Designer</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="team-member">
                        <img src="{% static "img/team/2.jpg" %}" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="">
                        <h4>Larry Parker</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Lead Marketer</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="team-member">
                        <img src="{% static "img/team/3.jpg" %}" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="">
                        <h4>Diana Pertersen</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Lead Developer</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                    <p class="large text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut eaque, laboriosam veritatis, quos non quis ad perspiciatis, totam corporis ea, alias ut unde.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Clients Aside -->
    <aside class="clients">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="{% static "img/logos/envato.jpg" %}" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="{% static "img/logos/designmodo.jpg" %}" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="{% static "img/logos/themeforest.jpg" %}" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="{% static "img/logos/creative-market.jpg" %}"class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Contact Us</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                <div id="success"></div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="copyright">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <ul class="list-inline quicklinks">
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Portfolio Modals -->
    <!-- Use the modals below to showcase details about your portfolio projects! -->

    <!-- Portfolio Modal 1 -->
    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
                            <h2>Project Name</h2>
```

Comment: What's you directory structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `settings.py`, instead of `STATIC_DIRS`, you should use:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS= (
    os.path.join(MAIN_DIR,'static'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.dirname(__file__)` points to the path where the `setting.py` is. For my directory structure:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../static/').replace('\\','/'),
)
```

directory structure:

```
porject
|--app
    |--settings.py
|--static
```